# Ruby Regex exclude if doest exist

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to parse my app logs with this Ruby Regex:

```
^time="?(?<timeapp>.*?)"? level="?(?<loglevel>.*?)"? msg="?(?<log>.*)"? trace-id=?(?<trace_id>.*?)$
```

The log is:

```
time="2022-09-29T13:47:57Z" level=info msg="[AP] SKU:prem_30d_01.09.2018_1065_2_offer_trial, userID:202222" guid=cFhblwnH5 trace-id=75dddd-EFW
```

Buy Ive faced a problem that trace-id= is not always in logs. Cannot find how to exclude trace-id parsing IF it doesn't exist in logs

https://rubular.com/r/NblAOyyZbvXaDW

Comment: Do you have quotes inside your quoted strings? If so, that'll need some augmentation. Note: This is why logging in JSON form is always better *if* that's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are looking for a space character **after** your msg group:

```
msg="?(?<log>.*)"? trace-id=
```

(so right between the *?* and *t* from trace). I imagine that if trace is not present, neither is that space character so thats why it doesnt match.
Making that space character optional, say with `\s?` would lead to your *msg=* group being greedy and grabbing everything, regardless of whether its there or not.

this might not be the best solution, as instead of matching any character i just limited it to the ones you would expect (`[a-zA-Z\[\]0-9\"=:_\.,\s]`):

```
^time="?(?<timeapp>.*?)"? level="?(?<loglevel>.*?)"? msg="?(?<log>[a-zA-Z\[\]0-9\"=:_\.,\s]*)"?(\strace-id=?(?<trace_id>.*?))?$
```

Comment: Just trying to place anything inside "msg=". If it was an option could be awesome. As I find out "guid=" could not exist as well, but it should be (or not if it doest exist) in "msg="